# Error MSB3095 when compiling a Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, msbuild

When I try to compile any Windows form application project, I get an error saying:

> \MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2114,5): error MSB3095: Invalid argument. Culture is not supported.

> \MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2114,5): error MSB3095: Parameter name: name

> \MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2114,5): error MSB3095: x86 is an invalid culture identifier.

I was using VS 2017 when I stumbled across this error message. After searching the net, I saw that the problem I had was never asked by someone else. So I uninstalled anything related to Visual Studio and installed VS 2019.

With all my efforts to solve this problem going down, I checked if there was a conflict with my application's references and the MSBuild assembly files. This was also not the solution. Right now I am two weeks behind my schedule and yet still have no answers.

I tried changing platform target and target framework, hoping to see a difference but no; nothing has changed.

I also tried other application projects & targets. Here is the result:
Compiling a console application does not raise an error message.
Compiling a Windows Forms application, however raises the same error message with different projects.

Comment: Can you share the csproj file? I suggest trying to use binary logs (`msbuild -bl` from the developer command line to create `msbuild.binlog` files) and the [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com) to investigate how `x86` ended up as a culture. Also check your environment variables to see if they have some generic variable name (`Platform`, `Culture`) set.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with .refresh files, you can check if  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906137/teamcity-building-project-failed-to-start-msbuild-exe-illegal-characters-in-pat) helps. And please go Tool=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>Build and Run=>Change Output verbosity to `Details` to see more details about the error message.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I am %100 sure that the problem is about MSBuild itself. I have created some new Windows Form Application projects to see if it is only with my main project but I got the same error message.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I did what you said and here is the build log file: https://shrib.com/#msbuild3095error

Comment: @FeritYiğitBALABAN yes it may as well be, but a repro would be good. Would you be able to share a binary log of your build or a build this occurs with? If it also occurs when using `msbuild` from the developer command prompt, you can use `-bl` to get this log, but see [this information about binary logs](https://gist.github.com/dsplaisted/b256d7804672a6f6375476a5f5658b7b) first.

Comment: The problem is that the code path inside MSBuild that logs this exception is super generic so it's hard to tell what could have gone wrong...

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, @MartinUllrich.

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question you should post it as an answer, not edit the question.

Comment: @FeritYiğitBALABAN do NOT update a question as "Solved". If you have a solution that is not already in an answer, add an answer. You can then mark that answer as "Accepted".

Comment: OK, I did that as you said, thanks! @Servy

Comment: You don't need to put "SOLVED" in the title. Everyone can see that the question has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to error MSB3095 is actually not totally specific but it may be caused by the directory which your project is in, like it was in my case.

So simply move your project to another directory, that **does not consist a non-ASCII character** in. It will most likely solve it.